# check is an object is fully empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

this object has properties, but no values, or at least empty arrays. I would like to do a condition checking if the object test has no content in the array then return true.

```
const test = {
  "10": [],
  "1": []
};

const output = Object.entries(cl).every(element => Object.values(element).some(val =>  val === "");

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Should this include checking for properties that are not arrays or that are null value?  If yes then the answers using length would cause an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the code inside some(). Check arrays length

```
const output = Object.entries(clientData).every(element => Object.values(element).some(val => Array.isArray(element) && val.length == 0);

const test = {
    "106596": [],
    "107014": []
     };


Output : false
```

---

When added an element inside test's element's array ;

```
const test = {
     "106596": [1],
     "107014": []
    };


Output : true
```

Comment: Will this work if the property is not an array?  The question seems to include all possible data types.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answers, with the addition of checking for an empty object.

```js
const pass1 = {};
const pass2 = { 123: [] }
const pass3 = { 123: [], 234: [] }
const fail1 = { 123: [], 234: [1] }

const isEmpty = (o) => !Object.keys(o).length || Object.values(o).every(a => !a.length);

[pass1,pass2,pass3,fail1].forEach(item => console.log(isEmpty(item)));
```

`0` is falsey, so `a.length` is enough, you don't need to check `a.length == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

There are – as you can see – many ways to implement this functionality, my own approach is below, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
const test = {
  "106596": [],
  "107014": []
},
// we declare a function to check if the array-values are empty,
// we pass in the Object we're testing, and from we use
// Object.values() to retrieve the values of the Object; we
// then iterate over the array-values using Array.prototype.every():
arrayValuesEmpty = (obj) => Object.values(obj).every(
  // along with an anoymous Arrow function to check if the
  // current array-element value ('val') is an Array (using
  // Array.isArray() and that its length property is exactly zero:
    (val) => Array.isArray(val) && val.length === 0
);

console.log(arrayValuesEmpty(test));
```

The above does have some naive assumptions, that all the Object values are Arrays and assumes that the passed-in argument will be an Object with properties; to guard against those assumptions:

```js
const test = {
    // adding new properties, String, Number and Boolean:
    stringProperty: 'Steven',
    numericalProperty: 3,
    booleanProperty: false,
    "106596": [],
    "107014": []
  },
  // here we pass in a default value (empty Object) to the function if
  // the user supplies no argument:
  arrayValuesEmpty = (obj = {}) => {
    // here we retrieve a two-dimensional Array of all Object entries,
    // in [key, value] arrays:
    const entries = Object.entries(obj);

    // if the length of entries in the Array of entries is zero we have
    // an empty Object (so no point continuing):
    if (entries.length === 0) {
      // returning false from the function:
      return false;
    }
   // otherwise we use Array.prototype.map() create a new Array:
   return entries.map(
    // using destructuring to assign the first array-element
    // to the (unused) 'key' variable, and the second (property-value
    // for the current entry) to the 'val' variable; and return that
    // 'val' (property-value of the original Object):
    ([key,val]) => val)
      // we then filter that Array of values using Array.prototype.filter():
      .filter(
        // passing the val variable to the function (the property-value of
        // the original Object) to return a new Array of Object-values
        // which are Arrays (checking with Array.isArray):
        (val) => Array.isArray(val)
      // then iterating over the Array-values using Array.prototype.every():
      ).every(
        // here we're checking if the Array-length is exactly zero:
        (val) => val.length === 0
      // if every Array-element is empty, so the length of every Array-element
      // is exactly zero then Array.prototype.every() returns Boolean true,
      // which is returned from the function:
      );
  };

console.log(arrayValuesEmpty(test));
```

References:

- [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
- [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).
- [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).
- [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

Comment: This is definitely one of those problems that seem simple at first until one considers all the possible outcomes.  +1

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, the simple bare-bones implementation is pretty easy, but the edge-cases can increase complexity; though I've certainly not covered all possible problems, after all: should it handle JSON strings of Objects? If an Array is passed instead of an Object? Those are easy enough to build in but unless OP decides to request further complexity I'm happy to leave it as-is for now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `values` by `Object.values`, and loop through and check if the `value` is an array, then check the length of the array equal to zero, if not check if the value equal `null` or `undefined`

```js
const test = {
  "106596": [],
  "107014": [],
};

const test2 = {
  "106596": [5],
  "107014": [],
};

const test3 = {
  "106596": [],
  "107014": [],
  "121123": 'something',
};


function checkEmpty(value) {
  return Object.values(value).every(element => Array.isArray(element) ? element.length === 0 : [null, undefined].includes(element));
}
 

console.log(checkEmpty(test));  // true
console.log(checkEmpty(test2)); // false
console.log(checkEmpty(test3)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

An option that would check for array and non null / undefine could use the object.values & filter like this

Object.values:
Returns all the values of an object

```
const is_empty : boolean = (item) => !Object.values(item).filter(n => (Array.isArray(n) && n.length > 0) || n === null || n === undefined ).length > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const test = {
    "106596": [],
    "107014": []
  };
  
  const getKeys = Object.keys(test);
  const checkVal = getKeys.map((item)=> test.[item].length);
  const result = checkVal.some(e => e)
  console.log(result)
```

You can do this in one step instead of this, hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

```js
const test = {
  one: [],
  two: [],
  three: undefined,
  hasVal: "Has Value!!",
  nullVal: null,
};

// loop
// you can ignore key
for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(test)) {
  // condintion
  if (val !== null && val !== undefined && val.length != 0) {
    console.log(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).